# SQL statement to return max date and the id associated with that max date

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to write a query that returns the max date for the entire table. However, I want to return some associated records/columns for that max date. For example, the id that is associated with that max date.

Table:

| account_number | date | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | 2004-01-01 | shirt |
| 145236 | 2006-07-01 | pant |
| 123156 | 2008-01-11 | shirt |
| 145347 | 2014-01-01 | shirt |

I want to return the max date across the entire table as well as the identifying ID record. This way I know which record returned the max date as well as the max date.

This is what I have tried:
select t1.account_number, max_date from db2.table t1
join (select account_number, max(date) as max_date from db2.table group by id) t2
on t1.account_number= t2.account_number and t1.date = t2.max_date

Result:
I return a row for each account_number with a max date. Instead, I am expecting a single row output with:

| account_number | date |
| --- | --- |
| 145347 | 2014-01-01 |

Comment: please synchronize sample data and desired output. in the sample data there is no ID-column and max date, as far as I can see, is '2014-01-01', not '2008-01-11'

Comment: Take a look at lateral https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=clause-lateral-derived-tables  Think of lateral as execute the next SQL statement once for each record returned on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT X.account_number,X.date FROM
 ( 
   SELECT T.account_number,T.date,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY T.DATE DESC)XCOL
     FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 )X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

You can try ROW_NUMBER-logic as above

Answer (score 0):

Either of the below could work.

select account_number, date from t1 order by date desc fetch first 1 row only

select account_number, max(date) as max_date from t1 group by act_num order by max_date desc fetch first 1 row only

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `ORDER BY` with `FECTH NEXT n ROWS ONLY`. For example:

```
select * from t order by date desc fetch next 1 rows only
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this query several times to produce a report similar to what you are asking:

```
select account_number, date 
  from ascrecs 
 where date in (select max(date) from ascrecs)   
   for read only with ur;
```